# Remove all lines except those containing one dot

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of data (abstract) and I need to remove all the lines containing more than one dot or containing no dots. Example:

```
two.dots.are.too.much
onedot.isacceptable
more.than.one.dot.needs.to.be.removed
zerodotsarenotacceptable
```

In this case, I need to keep only the second phrase, containing only one dot (`.`). How can this be done with RegEx in Notepad++?

Comment: no, lines with no dots are not acceptable

Comment: Another way: [`^[^\n.]*(?:\.[^\n.]*\..*)?(?:\n|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/eZ8vN2/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply search for `^(?:(?=(?:.*\.){2})|(?!.*\.)).*$\R?` and replace it with an empty string.

[image]

This will turn

```
two.dots.are.too.much
onedot.isacceptable
more.than.one.dot.needs.to.be.removed
zerodotsarenotacceptable
```

to

```
onedot.isacceptable
```

Comment: Not working. Keeps the line with the dot, but adds the string as a prefix. Keep also another line with the string used as token. Doesn't keep one of the lines. So now I'd have 2 lines, one with the acceptable data, one with just the string I've used as replacement. Hope I make sense. I've used the same 3 lines as above.

Comment: So I guess this was my mistake, cause I've added a string as replacemenet. Might work otherwise.

Comment: Edited it according to the edit to your question. For me it is working in Notepad++